# Fourier transform of $\frac{2\sin(x)}{1+x^2}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to calculate FT of $$f(x)=\frac{2\sin(x)}{1+x^2}$$
First of all we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{2\sin(x)}{1+x^2}\right| \, dx\leq 2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx=2\pi
$$
thus $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is well defined. Now let's compute $\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)$:
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}}{1+x^2} \, dx = \left[\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right]=\\=-i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-2\pi ix\xi + ix}-e^{-2\pi ix\xi -ix}}{1+x^2}\, dx$$

Now I'm not sure how to proceed further. Any help?

Comment: I think you can use the Residue's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using the convolution theorem.

You should first verify for yourself that

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{2\pi e^{-|2\pi\xi|}\right\} = \dfrac{2}{1+x^2}$$

and that

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\sin(x)\right\} = \dfrac{i}{2}\delta\left(\xi + \dfrac1{2\pi}\right)-\dfrac{i}{2}\delta\left(\xi - \dfrac1{2\pi}\right)$$

By the convolution theorem

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{2}{1+x^2} \cdot \sin(x)\right\} &= \mathcal{F}\left\{\dfrac{2}{1+x^2} \right\} * \mathcal{F}\left\{\sin(x)\right\} \\
\\
&= 2\pi e^{-|2\pi\xi|} \space * \space \left[\dfrac{i}{2}\delta\left(\xi + \dfrac1{2\pi}\right)-\dfrac{i}{2}\delta\left(\xi - \dfrac1{2\pi}\right)\right]\\
\\
&= i\pi \left( e^{-\left| 2\pi\left(\xi + \frac1{2\pi}\right)\right|}-e^{-\left| 2\pi\left(\xi - \frac1{2\pi}\right)\right|}\right)\\
\\
&= i\pi \left( e^{-\left| 2\pi\xi +1 \right|}-e^{-\left| 2\pi\xi-1\right|}\right)\\ 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Define the upper semi-circle with center in origin and redius $R$ as the contour and when $z=i$ is a pole of 
$$\int_{C}\frac{e^{-2\pi ix\xi + ix}-e^{-2\pi ix\xi -ix}}{1+x^2}dx$$
in $C$, find the residue, then you can simplify the integral.